How can I make my class accept between 2 different properties?
I have the following class:
public class MonthlyQuota
{
    public virtual EmployeeVacationForm Form { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateEmployeeSubmitted => Form?.DateCreated;
    
    public MonthlyQuota(QuarterlylSupport document)
    : this()
    {
        Document = document;
    }

    internal MonthlyQuota(
        QuarterlylSupport document, 
        EmployeeVacationForm form)
            : this(document)
    {
        Form = form;
        form.QuotaResult = this;
    }
    
    

It is used like this:
var staffResults = vacations.Select(vf => new MonthlyQuota(vf));    //where `vf` is the vacation form

Right now, it only needs EmployeeVacationForm, but I need to add another form called EmployeeVacationForm_Remote and call it like this:
var staffResults = vacations.Select(rvf => new MonthlyQuota(rvf));    //where `rvf` is the remote vacation form

So in my MonthlyQuota class, how can I have the Form object be either EmployeeVacationForm or EmployeeVacationForm_Remote?
Thanks!

To have the Form property in your MonthlyQuota class accept either EmployeeVacationForm or EmployeeVacationForm_Remote, you can define a base class or interface that both EmployeeVacationForm and EmployeeVacationForm_Remote inherit or implement. Then you can use this common base class or interface as the type for the Form property.
Assuming you have a base class BaseEmployeeVacationForm, you can modify your MonthlyQuota class as follows:
    public class MonthlyQuota
{
    public virtual BaseEmployeeVacationForm Form { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateEmployeeSubmitted => Form?.DateCreated;
    
    public MonthlyQuota(QuarterlySupport document)
    {
        Document = document;
    }

    public MonthlyQuota(QuarterlySupport document, BaseEmployeeVacationForm form)
        : this(document)
    {
        Form = form;
        form.QuotaResult = this;
    }
}

In this case, both EmployeeVacationForm and EmployeeVacationForm_Remote should inherit from BaseEmployeeVacationForm. This way, you can pass any object that is a subclass of BaseEmployeeVacationForm into the Form property of MonthlyQuota.
Then, when you create a MonthlyQuota object, you can pass either an EmployeeVacationForm or EmployeeVacationForm_Remote:
var staffResults = vacations.Select(vf => new MonthlyQuota(document, vf));
var remoteStaffResults = remoteVacations.Select(rvf => new MonthlyQuota(document, rvf));
Remember to adjust your EmployeeVacationForm and EmployeeVacationForm_Remote classes to inherit from BaseEmployeeVacationForm.

Is there a way to do it if there is no base class?  Thanks!

If you want the Form object in your MonthlyQuota class to be either an EmployeeVacationForm or an EmployeeVacationForm_Remote without a common base class, you can achieve this by using a common interface that both classes implement.
Here's how you can modify your MonthlyQuota class:
public class MonthlyQuota
{
    public virtual IEmployeeVacationForm Form { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateEmployeeSubmitted => Form?.DateCreated;
    
    public MonthlyQuota(QuarterlylSupport document, IEmployeeVacationForm form)
    {
        Document = document;
        Form = form;
        form.QuotaResult = this;
    }
}

Then, you can define an interface IEmployeeVacationForm that both EmployeeVacationForm and EmployeeVacationForm_Remote will implement:
public interface IEmployeeVacationForm

    {
        DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        MonthlyQuota QuotaResult { get; set; }
        // Any other properties or methods needed
    }

Just make sure that both EmployeeVacationForm and EmployeeVacationForm_Remote implement the interface with the required properties (DateCreated, QuotaResult, etc.).
